# Is exporting 2d planes within a 3d object file possible?

Tags: export, 2d

I know you can track the camera to make planes face the camera to appear 2d (for effects, fake lights, etc which need to always face the camera/view to work right), but I'm wondering if there's another way, which can be exported and loaded within whatever 3d viewer you use (like a .glb or .gltf). Or if there's an illusion that can achieve this.